# Display and download data from database blob

Tags: php, mysql, blob

i have this script that insert files into database blob type.
I can see the file name, but i cannot open/download the file
as you can see i tried the echo but seems it doesn't start to download the file

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
 <input type="file" name="myfile"/>
 <button name="btns"> Incarca Schita </button>
 </form>
 <?php
 $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=highmob_comenzi", "highmob", "PW");
 if(isset($_POST['btns'])){
     $name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
     $type = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
     $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE players SET data='$myfile', name='$name', mime='$type' WHERE id='$id'");
     $stmt->bindParam(1,$name);
     $stmt->bindParam(2,$type);
     $stmt->bindParam(3,$data);
     $stmt->execute();
 }
 ?>
 <?php
 $stat = $dbh->prepare("select * from players where id='$id'");
 $stat->execute();
 while($row = $stat->fetch()){
     echo "<a href='".$row['data']."'>".$row['name']."</a>
     ";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: you didn't RTM on this

Comment: what do you mean by RTM?

Comment: R=Read - T=The - M=Manual.

Comment: well trust me i read a lot of tutorials to do this. i really got stuck here

Comment: well, whatever they were, they either were bad/wrong or you didn't follow them "to a T".

Comment: maybe, i watched youtube tutorials like hole day the last echo its a link to a new page but i don't need the link to new page i need the link to the file :)

Comment: Don't watch tutorials, use the manual

Comment: well tutorials were what i needed :(